# Resources for webcam streaming with controls

Tags: video, streaming, embed, webcam

I'm looking a project right that would require 2 webcams to be streamed and have the stream embedded onto a web page with the ability to pan/tilt/zoom.

I know most of this is going to be on the type of camera and the camera hardware, but I'm not sure as to what direction to go as far as the streaming and embedding with controls. Don't know if I need to look at a red5 or flash streaming server and if I need to look at some custom development for getting the controls to map through so that the end user can control the pan/tilt/zoom functions of the camera.

If anyone has any insight, it will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use the [motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome) software on Linux, which automatically runs a webserver where you can view the cameras, and additionally has the feature of only recording video periods where there is motion detected (hence the name). This helps to save disk space.

I'm not sure if it has good support for pan/tilt though.

This might be a better question for the [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) site.